# Finding an angle given two sides and two angles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Consider the triangle given in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7o6lm.png). How to compute uniquely $\beta$ given $a$, $b$, $\alpha$, and $\gamma$? The double strikes on the figure indicate that the lines are parallel.

[image]

Comment: you must use the theorem of sines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Using the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), we are able to find the value of the third side of the triangle, $c$:

$$c = \sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\alpha+\gamma)}.$$

We can use again the law of cosines to find the angle $\delta$. In particular, we start from this:

$$b^2 = a^2 + c^2 - 2ac \cos(\delta),$$

and we arrive to:

$$\delta = \arccos\left(\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{2ac}\right).$$

Finally, we can easily obtain $\beta$:

$$\beta = \pi - \alpha - \delta.$$